# Determine if a Shape / View in SwiftUI will cover an existing Shape / View

Tags: ios, swiftui, shapes

I have a simple app that will put some shapes on the screen, but it is currently possible for the user to mask an existing one, which I want to avoid.

First, here is some simple code to provide an MVP for my project:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Circle()
                .fill(Color.red)
                .frame(width: 44,
                       height: 44)
                .zIndex(1.0)
            
            Circle()
                .fill(Color.blue)
                .frame(width: 55,
                       height: 55)
                .zIndex(2.0)
        }
    }
}
```

This image shows the above code in action:

[image]

However, when the `zIndex` is flipped, as shown here, the blue completely obscures the red.

[image]

I'd rather not have the user be able to do this, but I have yet to find something within SwiftUI that can determine if the shape is completely covered or not.

Answer (score 0):

You might try to represent each shape as a struct with it's own size and coordinate (x and y). Existing shapes are to be put in array. Whenever user drags the shape, you update the values and check wether it's size and coordinates are identical to some shape from array (you can do it when the gesture ends or while it is happening. it's up to you). If condition is met you either move static shape away by some *k* or show user in any way that he is unable to drop shape at that place